# Is ${\displaystyle \left\{{\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}},\;\;n\notin\mathbb{P}\right\}}$ dense in $(0,1)$?

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function

Sierpiński and Schinzel proved
${\displaystyle \left\{{\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}},\;\;n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}}$ is dense in the
interval $(0,1)$ where $n$ is a natural number
and $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function#Ratio_of_consecutive_values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Ratio_of_consecutive_values)

Is the set still dense in the same interval with the added restriction ${\displaystyle \left\{{\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}},\;\;n\notin\mathbb{P}\right\}}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of prime numbers?

Comment: $\phi(p^2)/p^2=\phi(p)/p,$ so there primes don't add anything. You really want to remove prime powers.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Note that
$$\left\{{\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}},n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} = \left\{{\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}},n\in\Bbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{P}\right\} \cup \left\{\frac{n-1}{n} : n \in \Bbb{P}\right\}.$$
The latter set admits only a single accumulation point: $1$. So, if we take a sequence from $\{\varphi(n)/n : n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ that converges to $x \in (0, 1)$, then only finitely many sequence terms can belong to $\{(n-1)/n : n \in \Bbb{P}\}$, so the (infinite) tail of the sequence must belong to $\{\varphi(n)/n : n \in \Bbb{N} \setminus \Bbb{P}\}.$

Comment: If you want the slightly stronger conclusion of density in $[0, 1]$, then by a similar argument all we need to do is worry about sequences converging to $1$. To get this, just take $n = pq$ for sufficiently large, distinct primes $p$ and $q$. Then $\varphi(n)/n = (p - 1)(q - 1) / (pq) \to 1$ as $p, q \to \infty$.

Comment: @ Theo Bendit Right. $\frac{\varphi(n)}{n} = \frac{n-1}{n}$ also when $n$ is a power of a prime. Is the convergence to $1$ due to the denominator being quadratic rather than linear in the sense that the harmonic series is divergent, whereas the sum of inverse squares converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Comment: No, it's more to do with the sequence $(p - 1)/p$ being a subsequence of the sequence $(n - 1)/n = 1 - 1/n$, and as $n \to \infty$, $1/n \to 0$. This is more elementary than the observation that $\sum 1/n$ diverges or that $\sum 1/n^2$ converges. In fact, series are not really a part of this.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $A$ is a set dense in $(0,1)$ and $a_n\in A$ is a sequence such that $a_n\to 1,$ then $A\setminus \{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is dense in $(0,1).$

This can be fairly easily proved.

---

You don't really need $a_n\to 1,$ just that $a_n$ converges. But in your case, $a_n=\frac{\phi(p_n)}{p_n},$ converges to $1.$

As I noted in comments, $\frac{\phi(p^k)}{p^k}=\frac{\phi(p)}{p},$ so actually, you aren't even removing any values just by remove the primes $n$. But if you remove the prime powers $n,$ you can use the above argument.